# OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dsize.area() > 0 || (inv_scale_x > 0 && inv_scale_y > 0)) in cv::resize

Tags: opencv, resize, satellite-image

I'm trying to resize two satellite images using OpenCV. I provide the code:

```
import rasterio
import cv2

print('[INFO] Reading Images ...')
start = time.time()
with rasterio.open(image1_path) as image1:
    image1 = image1.read()
end = time.time()
print('[INFO] Reading Images took {} seconds'.format(end-start))
print(image1)

new_size = np.asarray(image1.shape) /5
new_size = new_size.astype(int) *5
image1 = cv2.resize(np.array(image1).astype('float32'), (new_size[0],new_size[1]))
```

It reports the following error:

**OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dsize.area() > 0 || (inv_scale_x > 0 && inv_scale_y > 0)) in cv::resize, file C:\ci\opencv_1512688052760\work\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp, line 3290
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "DetectChange.py", line 96, in 
image1 = cv2.resize(np.array(image1).astype('float32'), (new_size[0],new_size[1])).astype(int)
cv2.error: C:\ci\opencv_1512688052760\work\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:3290: error: (-215) dsize.area() > 0 || (inv_scale_x > 0 && inv_scale_y > 0) in function cv::resize**

Images are read correctly. I searched for other similar errors, but none exactly looks like mine.

Comment: You need to do some debugging. Do the values you're feeding to `resize` make sense? | What's the point of `np.array(image1)` -- `image1` is already a numpy array, isn't it?